# How to validate dropdown only if a checkbox located in the same row is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to perform validation on some dropdownlist present in a gridview.

When a user clicks a button without selecting an option, the user should be prompted with an alert message that the dropdownlist is not selected.

My `gridview` control contains three columns:

1. checkbox
2. label control
3. dropdownlist

I only want to perform validation on the dropdownlist that the row is selected by the checkbox. The problem is that it performs validation for all the dropdownlist, irrespective if the checkbox is checked or not.

jQuery:

```
$("#btnStartExam").click(function (evt) {
    debugger;
    ($("#grdEnglish option:selected")).each(function () {
        if ($("#grdEnglish input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') && ($(this).val() == 'Select Year')){
            alert('Select year');
            ($(this).parent().css("background-color", "red"));
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeholderSubjects">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <p>COMPULSORY SUBJECT</p>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdEnglish" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SUBJECTS" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SUBJECTS" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl" Text='<%#Eval("sub")%>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EXAMINATION YEAR" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Select Year">Select Year</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnStartExam" runat="server" Text="START EXAMINATION" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Anyway you can show some of your html of the rows?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Is your alert() being called for every dropdown? What issue are you having? You are looping through all dropdowns because each dropdown should default to 'Select Year' option. If you want to loop through only the checked ones, then you should use `$("#grdrEnglish input[type='checkbox']").each(function() { if (this.checked) { // row checked } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the row you are in when you work through each selected option. Do so with a .closest('tr') call to get the row the option is in, and then find the input based on that. I would also suggest handling the error a different way than alerting like that. Perhaps keep track of them in an array or object and then perform one alert at the end, outside of the loop.

```
$("#btnStartExam").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();    // without this it will submit
    ($("#grdEnglish option:selected")).each(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if (row.find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') && ($(this).val() == 'Select Year')) {
            alert('Select year');
            (row.css("background-color", "red"));
        }
    });
});
```

Incidentally, since you are working with ASP.Net here, have you considered using an ASP CustomValidator instead? This will allow you to set the form's valid state directly.

You could put something like this function in your head instead of the jQuery you have:

```
function validateRow(src, args) {
    var row = $(src).closest('tr');
    var chk = row.find("input[type='checkbox']")[0];
    if (chk.checked  && args.Value == 'Select Year') {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else { args.IsValid = true;}
}
```

And add something like the following beneath your DropDownList:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="customYearValidator" ControlToValidate="drp" ErrorMessage="Please select a year" ClientValidationFunction="validateRow"></asp:CustomValidator>
```